# How to add a string and integer into a file and then sort it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my code the program asks for the users name and score. However I can send the score to a file and sort it. Is there any way to change the code so that the player name gets sent to the file and also sorts along with its corresponding number.

```
player_1=input('What is your name?')
points1=input('What is your score?')
player_2=input('What is your name?')
points2=input('What is your score?')

leaderboard=input('Type YES if you would like to see the tp scores and NO if you wouldnt')
while leaderboard=='YES':
    Scorefile=open('scores.txt','a')
    Scorefile.write(points1)
    Scorefile.write("\n")
    Scorefile.write(points2)
    Scorefile.write("\n")
    Scorefile.close()
    Scorefile = open('scores.txt','r')
    with open('scores.txt','r') as Scorefile:
        scores=Scorefile.readline()
        List1=[]
        while scores:
            scores2=(scores.strip())
            List1.append(scores2)
            scores=Scorefile.readline()
    for i in range(0, len(List1)):
        List1[i] = int(List1[i])        
    List1.sort(reverse=True)

    print(List1[0:5])
    leaderboard='ANYTHING'
while leaderboard=='NO':
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Yes, there is a way to do it. What do you need help with? Please read [ask].

Comment: Also this code could really use a rewrite. For example you know how to use a `with` statement, so why are you manually opening and closing `scores.txt`? Why do you use `while` instead of `if`? Why do you do `sys.exit()` instead of just letting it exit on its own? Why do you only write 5 scores back to the file?

Comment: Also, use `print(points1, points2, sep='\n', file=Scorefile)`

Answer (score 0):

Why not create 2 files and have the 1st file store strings and 2nd file store ints.
Then extract the info if needed from both. Very simple and easy.

Comment: if i did that how would i sort the strings

Comment: I'm very confused by what you means sort the strings. Like Alphabetical order? I would need more information to help me understand what your meaning of "sort" is.